# What is the best Collection Type to use to get the permutations of 2 different enums

Tags: c#, list, enums, iterator

I am seeking out the right collection type to achieve this result in C#. I am wanting to create a List of Items, from a couple of enum fields I've pre-specified.

- itemType
- itemMaterial

For every itemType I add, I would like for a new set of items to be created that follows this general pattern, (ripped from Runescape for ease of concept conveyance, don't come after me JaGex):

```
ItemType enum:
Helmet, Platebody, Platelegs, Boots

ItemMaterial enum: 
Bronze, Iron, Steel, Black, White, Mithril, Adamant, Rune, Dragon...

Items List(?):
    BronzeHelmet, IronHelmet, SteelHelmet, BlackHelmet, WhiteHelmet, MithrilHelmet, AdamantHelmet, RuneHelmet, DragonHelmet
    BronzePlatebody, IronPlatebody, SteelPlatebody, BlackPlatebody, WhitePlatebody, MithrilPlatebody, AdamantPlatebody, RunePlatebody, DragonPlatebody
    BronzePlatelegs, IronPlatelegs, SteelPlatelegs, BlackPlatelegs, WhitePlatelegs, MithrilPlatelegs, AdamantPlatelegs, RunePlatelegs, DragonPlatelegs
    BronzeBoots, IronBoots, SteelBoots, BlackBoots, WhiteBoots, MithrilBoots, AdamantBoots, RuneBoots, DragonBoots
```

If anybody knows the best data type to achieve something like this with, or maybe the right methods for it that allow you to iterate the combination of the two, I would appreciate it so much.

```
enum ItemType
{
    FullHelmet,
    MediumHelmet,
    Platebody,
    Chainbody,
    Platelegs,
    Plateskirt,
    Boots,
    Shoes,
    KiteShield,
    SquareShield,
    Battleaxe,
    WarHammer,
    Longsword,
    Shortsword,
    Dagger,
    Longbow,
    Shortbow,
    Crossbow,
    LongStaff,
    Staff,
    Wand
}

enum ItemQuality
{
    Wood,
    Bronze,
    Iron,   
    Steel,
    Black,
    Mithril,
    Adamant,
    Rune,
    Dragon,
    Barrows,
    GodWars,
    Elite
}
```

Comment: What can you do so far? Can you create a type that holds an ItemType and an ItemMaterial? Can you create a list of that type? Can you create a list of available ItemTypes? A list of available ItemMaterials? Can you merge those two lists into the one you want? Where *exactly* in this process are you stuck? Please post your code.

Comment: You don't appear to be looking for a collection type, but a way to get all permutations of two collections. The latter has been asked and answered before for various data types, have you found and tried any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a specific collection.  Just declare the item class and create all permutations.

Choosing a collection would be needed if you had specific requirements like quick access, fast iterations, one item pointing to another and more.

```
public class Item {
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }
    public ItemQuality Material { get; set; }

    public Item(ItemType type, ItemQuality material) {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Material = material;
    }
}
```

Since this is an enum, and it can't be dynamically created, in your startup create all the possible combinations:

```
List<Item> Items;
var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemType));
var materials = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemQuality));
foreach(ItemType type in types) {
    foreach(ItemQuality material in materials) {
        Items.Add(new Item(type, material));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. I just started learning C# about a couple months ago, so there's a lot of things I have yet to get the hang of, but I'm getting there!